# After uploading many files to S3 I see a folder ry/

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3-bucket

After uploading more than **100** files to an **S3 bucket** I see files in the grid as **ry/** 
If I search for them manually they don't exist. I'm assuming they are Temporary files or something. But can someone confirm this ? If not what is it ?

*Refer screenshot below:*

[image: console S3 screen]

Comment: Click on one of these files and show us what S3 believes the actual URL to the file is.  The `/` should not be showing in the console like this, so it does seem unusual... but it shouldn't be a temporary file.  What did you use to upload the files?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I used the website interface to upload. . Only clicking of those files it shows as they do not exist .

Comment: I would suggest trying `aws s3api list-objects ... --output text` to see what you see.  You might also post on the official forums.  For the moment, this seems to defy explanation.

Comment: ok Thanks I will try that